# SQL Group LEFT JOIN result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a couple of tables:

**Users**

id

**Settings**

user_id

I want to return the user details along with all settings for a given user accessible in the result under a 'settings' index, is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgresql has an `ARRAY_AGG` function that will do the concatenation for you. e.g.

```
SELECT  Users.ID, 
        ARRAY_AGG(COALESCE(Name || ' : ' || Value, '')) AS Settings
FROM    Users
        LEFT JOIN Settings
            ON Users.ID = Settings.User_ID
GROUP BY Users.ID
```

Your table structure was a little vague so the above is based on a schema I created on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c7d7e/1)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a index in user_id column, you could do something like this:

```
select u.*, s.*
from Users u
inner join Settings s on (u.id = s.user_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do what you want, if i well understood ...

```
SELECT Users.*, Settings.*
FROM Users 
JOIN Settings ON Settings.user_id = Users.id
```

Comment: This works, but what I want to do is for each user return a single row with their settings grouped under 'settings' in the result.

Comment: So, do you have more settings related to one user ?

Answer (score 0):

Try GROUP_CONCAT

Like this in mysql?

```
SELECT u.id, GROUP_CONCAT(s.id)  
FROM Users u  
INNER JOIN Settings s ON u.id = s.user_id 
GROUP BY u.id;
```

**EDIT:**

PostgreSQL version:

```
SELECT u.id, STRING_AGG(s.id)  
FROM Users AS u  
INNER JOIN Settings AS s ON u.id = s.user_id 
GROUP BY u.id;
```

Comment: PostgreSQL does not have a `group_concat` function. The equivalent PostgreSQL function is `string_agg`